# Javascript getting wrong value from selected box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a selected box like this

```
<form:select style="width:100%" path="partnerTransactionStatus" id="partnerTransactionStatus" class="form-control select2">
    <form:option value="-999" label="Tất cả"/>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${listIBFTPartnerResponseList}">
        <form:option value="${item.key}" label="${item.value}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

when i tried to use java script to get the selected value like this:

```
 var partnerTransactionStatus = $('#partnerTransactionStatus').val()
```

It's always return value = 1

the listIBFTPartnerResponseList is a hash map with key data type = String and value data type = String

This that javascript can't get String value of selected box ?

Comment: `.val()` should return the selected value. Can you recreate it and post it back on jsfiddle or code snippet

Comment: i can't it's a part of very huge system

Comment: @NguyễnVinh Show us generated HTML. Maybe your value actually *is* 1. Also try `$('#partnerTransactionStatus option:selected').val()`

Comment: problem solve , because another attribute have the same id so it take from the previous one